# Eliminating STPP taste in seafood

Tags: flavor, seafood

All of the IQF shrimp in local stores contain sodium tripolyphosphate. I am apparently very sensitive to the taste, or at least more so than my family members. It renders these shrimp inedible to me. Is there anything that I could marinade the shrimp in to possibly reduce some of the taste?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what does it taste like?

Comment: @logophobe It is almost a smell, not a taste, so very strong seasoning can mask it, but I describe it as tasting the way laundry bleach smells. I've had fish with STPP in it, and I don't taste it; I only taste it in shrimp, but never in fresh shrimp.

Comment: ...I can see why that would be extremely offputting!

Answer (score 1):

Shrimp can have up to 0.25% STPP, fish even more!

STPP reacts with calcium or magnesium salts. These are commonly found in pool PH buffers, or as gypsum (food grade gypsum is used as a tofu coagulant)

1 Kg of shrimp could have up to 2.5g of STPP, so a 1/2 tsp of a calcium or magnesium salt dissolved in hot water, and diluted to 1 l, would make a neutralising bath for 1 Kg of shrimp. Leave it in for 10 or 20 minutes and rinse thoroughly

It may also react with citric acid (used in baking), or just use the juice of a small lemon instead

The only problem with this is it may leave a soapy taste